Screenshot of the Week #129
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 129th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Wondercricket's screenshot from horizon-zero-dawn won with a whopping 18 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for (a little less than) a week, until November 26, 2024, then have a second 6-day-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone. The 6 day periods are exceptional, and there to shift back into our regular schedule.
After the end of the second week, at December 2, 2024, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Theme - Photorealism
This contest's theme is photorealism, so post any screenshots that are difficult to impossible to distinguish from real-life photographs.

As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Wondercricket, you have a very funny opportunity! ;)

Thanks for posting this. Been a  long week, and so this completely slipped my mind.

@Wipqozn and it’s only Wednesday

Woah we were reeeally late this week

Argh, I already posted the super realistic omelette x) Well, gotta cook up something else... Get it? Cook up... All right, I'll see myself out

@Wipqozn I had put the end date of the submission period to today, actually: 6 days for submissions, 6 days for voting, after which we would be back on track. (But based on the amount of submissions I don't think it would have made much of a difference :)

@Joachim At least I'm glad I didn't end up being the only one to submit a screenshot x)

@Joachim Whoops! didn't even notice.


metro-exodus

For some reasons, I thought I saw a crocodile

I'm calling shenanigans.  This is clearly an IRL picture.

I root for the logs

@arghtype Only if you have a head and a tail

Time to accept your winning answer!

Enjoying the scenery with the boys in our beloved Regalia.
final-fantasy-15


I guess the game doesn't exactly quality as photorealistic, but some shots are worthy of being a contender. I didn't have the time to search through my 6,000 screenshots though (gotta go to work), and this came out very nicely.

Funnily enough, I was thinking of some of the images of meals from the same game as possible contenders.

@DanielSchepler Yeah, some of these meals seriously look appetising. Like that Golden Egg Galette I had posted a few months ago. It looked very realistic, but alas I cannot repost it again x)



red-dead-redemption-2

For a moment I thought it was one of those creepy corridors in Half-Life: Alyx. Still, that's the kind of house I can see myself living in. Nice and cosy.
